# How do you turn a button in to an icon, in JSFiddle.

Tags: jsfiddle

Needing some help for a school project, and trying to figure out how to change the ascetics of my buttons by inserting jepg s or even gif s.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by specifing the inner content of the button or input as being an img tag

so normally `<button>Submit</button>` will create a button with submit as the text of the button instead you do this

```
<button id="btn"><img height="40" width="40" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/google-plus-icon.png"></img></button>
```